# How to access the context of a future created screen?

Tags: python

In this simple script below, i created a duplicata of the context editor into a new screen. all i want is to know the context.screen.name of both editors.

```
import bpy 
print(bpy.context.screen.name)
bpy.ops.screen.area_dupli('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
print(bpy.context.screen.name) #still the context of the old screen
```

when trying this script, all it print is the same context.screen.name twice.
How can i access future event like this?

Answer (score 1):

```
bpy.context.window_manager.windows[-1].screen.name
```

will be the name of the last created screen.